# Count spaces before a string value SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

so I have a table `TEST` with 2 columns - `id` and `value`. I would like a count of the number of spaces before a specific string value.

```
id         value
1          AB CD EFD RA
```

I would like a query to count the number of spaces in the value column to the left of `"EFD"`. In this case it should be 2.

Thanks!

I tried:

```sql
select ID,
       VALUE,
       regexp_substr(Value, 'EFD') AS "SUBSTRING", 
       regexp_instr(Value, 'EFD') AS "POSITION"
```

I would like to get the position of EFD in this array as well. I should get 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, value,
       regexp_substr(Value, 'EFD') AS substring, 
       regexp_count(substring(Value, 1, regexp_instr(Value, 'EFD')-1), ' ') AS spaces_before_EFD,
       regexp_instr(Value, 'EFD') AS position
from test;
```